# Force.com Toolkit for .NET Custom Field Naming

Tags: c#, .net, force.com-toolkit-for-net

I'm trying to update an Account record using the Force.com Toolkit for .NET. The Account record has custom fields.

I thought the toolkit allowed the [DataMember] attribute to be used, but its not working for me.

Is there any way to specify the custom field name to be used (namespace__Field_Name__c) without having to name my class property that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a Pull request to add this functionality [Support for DataMember attributes #126](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/pull/126). It was merged in on the 25th of August 2015 to be in the next NuGet release.

From [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DeveloperForce.Force/) this should correspond with v1.1.1 onward.

In terms of source code, I can see references to DataMemberAttribute in [ModelDescriptionGenerator.GetMemberName](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/5c391b30606569f18169d0cc4cd28d6fdaf6f404/samples/WebServerOAuthFlow/Areas/HelpPage/ModelDescriptions/ModelDescriptionGenerator.cs#L215). Note that in that method a JsonPropertyAttribute will take precedence to the DataMemberAttribute.

Comment: I'm using 1.1.1, and yes I saw those references in the code as well, and yet it appears to be ignoring the attributes - at least for the CreateAsync method.

Comment: Are you also using the JsonProperty attributes? It might be easiest to diagnose by pulling down the source and stepping through it.

Comment: Well the JsonProperty attribute works for me, but the DataMember attribute doesn't - however thats not your problem, so I accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe raise it as an issue on the Github project. Someone there will be well setup to trace the issue.